# Aws s3 pricing confusion in regards to "standard" and "not standard"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Per link below, there are two ways of pricing requests : the "standard way" and "otherwise not specified".

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

I am an average s3 user, i am assuming i get charged under the standard policy, ex 1 cent for 10k get requests.

Then how does one get under the "otherwise not specified" policy and get charged .4 cents per 10k get requests?

Or is my assumption wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different storage classes that you can read about: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/

By default your objects are stored as "Standard" and it is suitable for many needs. 1 cent for 10k requests is this class' price.

If you have large but not frequently needed data (like backups) you can consider other storage classes but if you really do not need it you don't have to bother about it for now.